# Dead? Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power, thinkpad

Ok, let's begin. A couple of weeks ago, My Lenovo Thinkpad X300 (2008) crapped out suddenly. I opened it up and inspected the components, nothing. Upon reopening I noticed that the DC jack was literally blacked out, like smouldered. So, instead of spending precious money on a replacement part, I soldered the AC cord to the cord out from the jack. The PC started perfectly fine. I insulated the wires well and managed to get the computer running. The computer could fully start up if the motherboard power was removed but then plugged back in. Great.

But then I stuffed it up. I realised that the fan needed a fresh thermal-paste up. So... I used methylated spirits to get the old thermal paste off of the CPU, graphics accelerator chip (which would be touching the copper on the cooler). I applied, and started trying to put the PC back together. However, I soon realised the computer had no sign of life. See, I could tell the PC had power, because the ethernet port would flash (along with the status light for AC and battery on the keyboard/top of the PC), followed by the fans spinning for a second, stopping, and then the computer would boot and VGA would start working. But this time, the Ethernet would flash, followed by quick split second flashes, as if the computer is tripping somewhere?! I removed the thermal paste and to my horror the same symptom occured!

What should I do! I waited for hours before testing again. I'm so sad, I've spent hours upon hours working on this computer to get it working. Maybe it's time it gives out the ghost. Any advice guys?

I've tried with:

DIMM+HDD attached

Disk drive attached

Fan attached

All combinations of those.

Does Thermal Paste And/Or methylated spirits have the ability to destroy components?

UPDATE: No, The thermal paste isn't the issue.

I have looked over every component alongside the CPU and graphic accelerator chips (Where thermal paste was) and have scrubbed all of them with the meths and a toothbrush. I have checked the board all over with a desk magnifying glass. I have no idea what it could be.

How do I look for broken components? This is getting far too surface-mount level for my liking! All help is appreciated, I do not know what to go with next. Something must be shorting, but it isn't the thermal paste. DIMM has been removed along with the network card to no avail now. Any last ditch advice before I give up?

Answer (score 0):

Some types of thermal paste (e.g. Arctic Silver) are electrically conductive. Such a paste can cause short circuits, if too much of the paste is used or some of the paste otherwise ends up in a wrong place.